# Typescript - Cannot list methods over an Object

Tags: typescript, introspection

I have a class like this:

```
export class A {

    @Decorator()
    public a(): void {
        ...
    }

    @Decorator()
    public b(): void {
        ...
    }

}
```

Later, having an instance of `A` (passed in as an `Object` though), I want to list all its methods. I thought that `Reflect.ownKeys( aInstance: Object )` could give me what I wanted, but the resulting array coming from the function is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in javascript the methods are part of the prototype of the constructor.

It's easier to see why if you look at the compiled javascript, for example this:

```
class A {
    public a(): void {}

    public b(): void {}
}
```

Compiles to:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
    }
    A.prototype.a = function () { };
    A.prototype.b = function () { };
    return A;
}());
```

So:

```
let a = new A();
console.log(Object.keys(a)); // []
console.log(Object.keys(a.constructor.prototype)); // ["a", "b"]
console.log(Object.keys(A.prototype)); // ["a", "b"]
```